# how to create windows installation package for my .inf?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, kmdf, dpinst

I have done the below steps:
1. built and compile my kernel driver which emulates tape device drivers.
2. created the needed .inf
3. created the needed .cat
4. signed the files
5. tested by manually "right click" -> install on the .inf file from explorer

Now I am ready to do a more easy installation package, but I do not know how this can be done?

I tried to create a directory C:\drivers
Where I also created a dpinst.xml file containing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <dpinst>

<suppressAddRemovePrograms/>

<!-- The following search and subDirectory elements direct
     DPInst to search all subdirectories (under the DPInst working directory) to locate driver
     packages. -->
    <search>
      <subDirectory>*</subDirectory>
    </search>

<!-- The following language element localizes its child elements
     for the English (Standard) language. The child elements
     customize the text that appears on the DPInst wizard pages. -->
    <language code="0x0409">
      <dpinstTitle>Device Driver Updater</dpinstTitle>
      <welcomeTitle>Welcome to the Device Installer!</welcomeTitle>
      <welcomeIntro>This wizard will walk you through updating the drivers for your device.</welcomeIntro>
      <installHeaderTitle>Installing the software for your device...</installHeaderTitle>
      <finishTitle>Congratulations! You finished installing your device drivers.</finishTitle>
    </language>

    <scanHardware/>

</dpinst>
```

And copied dpinst.exe
And created a subdirectory "storage" where I copied the .inf, .cat and .sys files to

When I try to install by double click on dpinst.exe from this directory; it gives message "no need (No device for update present)"

But this is not a PnP device driver? it is KMDF (Kernel Device Driver)?

Anyone have an idea how to create an installation package?

Best Regards Tomas

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try WDF installation package sample in WDK8.1 driver samples.

description of the sample:

WDF Installation Package-   installWdf  Demonstrates how to install WDF packages on a system. This code can be used as-is to install the needed WDF components onto a user system. The sample code can also be reworked into an existing setup application to provide a better experience.